# Get Open SqlConnection/SqlDataReader objects in code

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

I am developing a Web Application using ASP.NET 4/VB.NET with web forms and using MS SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced Edition as back end.

My application is huge and there are so many lines of code which contains `SqlDataReaders` and `SqlConnection` objects in huge numbers(hundreds of).

I took precautions to use `Using` statement and `Try.. Catch.. Finally` statements everywhere so that DataReader or Connection object is closed for sure.

Still, is there a way I can check from thousands of line of code, which DataReader or Connection I forgot to close?

Comment: You could make your own `DbDataReader` and `DbConnection` classes that would track this for you, but it's a bit annoying (ADO.NET isn't exactly designed for composition). Another option would be to enable tracing and write a simple program that would go through the trace logs to check if there's as many Closes as Opens.

Comment: I have some vague notion of using SQL Server Management Studio to `exec sp_who2` to find whatever is using the database, then refer to [Get Last Running Query Based on SPID](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/19/sql-server-get-last-running-query-based-on-spid/) to see the query. That query could lead you to the part of your code you're trying to find.

Comment: @Luaan Can you provide some example with this?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Can you also provide me some demo code?

Comment: if you were `using` each SqlDataReader and SqlConnection, then nothing should remain open after use as the end of the `using` statement calls `dispose` on the class, the dispose for both of these classes closes the reader/connection.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Your answer and help link was very useful. Thanks.

Comment: It's really simple, it's just a lot of work. Make your own class that derives from `DbCommand`, `DbDataReader`, `DbConnection`, `DbDataAdapter` etc., and have them take the actual command (or whatever) as an argument. Then override all the methods to call the underlying command (or whatever) and add logging when needed (debug-only finalizers can be quite useful for finding unclosed data readers and connections in particular). This works best if you already have some abstractions in place - if you e.g. tend to manually assign connections to commands, it's a bit trickier.

Comment: @Luaan Great and thank you so much